# Why Successive Approximation, Analog to Digital converter is most commonly used?

Tags: analog, digital

There are various types of ADC in used, like,

- ramp-compare ADC
- Wilkinson ADC
- pipeline ADC
- Flash ADCs
- Sub-Ranging ADCs
- Folding ADCs
- Pipelined ADCs
- Successive Approximation (Algorithmic) ADCs
- Integrating (serial) ADCs

but  Successive Approximation (Algorithmic) ADCs (ADC0808) is most commonly used.
I do not understand the reason as why it is better than any other ADC ?

According to this comparison,

[image]

There is absolutely nothing so special about it as compared to other, then why it is most commonly used for education purpose and small electronic projects etc ?

Comment: Nothing special about it? Look at the characteristics of the ADCs most commonly integrated on microcontrollers or used in small projects: medium precision (8-14 bits), medium speed (sample rates from a tens of kHz to a couple MHz), and as low-cost as possible. According to those criteria, you would select the successive approximation architecture from your matrix shown there.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), also.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electronic architectures, which are better off on electronics.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For many applications, the technology often selected is the lowest cost one that meets the most common requirements (audio sample rates, etc.)